# Does a filter function exist which stops when it finds the n'th first element corresponding to a predicate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I ask this question because i had to find one specific element on a RDD[key:Int,Array(Double)] where keys are unique. So it will be costly to use filter on the entire RDD whereas i just need one element which a know the key.

```
val wantedkey = 94
val res = rdd.filter( x => x._1 == wantedkey )
```

Thank you for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the **lookup** function at [PairRDDFunctions.scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions).

```
def lookup(key: K): Seq[V]

Return the list of values in the RDD for key key. This operation is 
done efficiently if the RDD has a known partitioner by only searching 
the partition that the key maps to.
```

Example

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("dog", "tiger", "lion", "cat", "panther", "eagle"), 2)
val b = a.keyBy(x => (_.length)
b.lookup(5)
res0: Seq[String] = WrappedArray(tiger, eagle)
```

Answer (score 1):

All [transformations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) are lazy and they are computed only when you call [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions) on them. So you can just write:

```
val wantedkey = 94
val res = rdd.filter( x => x._1 == wantedkey ).first()
```